# How should negative numbers be represented in the pymodbus input register?

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

I want to assign negative numbers to the input register in a pymodbus asynchronous server.  I have a 5 element array named PQV that contains numbers with magnitude ranging from 0 to 300, but some of the elements are negative

`PQV=[145, -210, 54, 187, -10]`

I use the code below to assign PQV to the Input Register (register 4) starting at address 0.  I tried adding 65536 to all the negative numbers, but that didn't work.

How do I condition the negative elements of array PQV to be acceptable for pymodbus?

```
context[slave_id].setValues(4, 0, PQV)
```

Comment: Refer payload server example https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/library/pymodbus.html#pymodbus.payload.BinaryPayloadDecoder. Tl;Dr, use [BinaryPayloadBuilder](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/library/pymodbus.html#pymodbus.payload.BinaryPayloadBuilder) to pack negative values.

Comment: A typical example in my case would be:     
`     circuitbreakerstatus = [1,1]     `  
`     busvoltages = [120.0,  501.3, -65.2]     `  
  
I have been trying:  
  
`context[slave_id].setValues(2, 0, circuitbreakerstatus)`  
`context[slave_id].setValues(4, 0, busvoltages)`  
  
it is not clear to me how I would use the `BinaryPayloadBuilder` to implement the context update for this simple case.  In this simple case how would I order the `builder.add...` statements and then incorporate into the `context[slave_id].setValues(...` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The floats are to be represented in IEEE-754 hex format before writing in to the datastore. You can do something like this to achieve it.

```
# Import BinaryPayloadBuilder and Endian
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadBuilder, Endian
# Create the builder, Use the correct endians for word and byte
builder = BinaryPayloadBuilder(byteorder=Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Big)
```

In your updating function

```
busvoltages = [120.0, 501.3, -65.2, 140.3, -202.4]
builder.reset() # Reset Old entries
for vol in busvoltages:
    builder.add_32bit_float(vol)
payload = builder.to_registers()   # Convert to int values
# payload will have these values [17136, 0, 17402, 42598, 49794, 26214, 17164, 19661, 49994, 26214]
context[slave_id].setValues(2, 0, payload)  # write to datablock
```

When you read the values back , you will get the raw int values back. You will have to convert them back to floats using `BinaryPayloadDecoder`

```
>>> from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder, Endian
>>> r = client.read_input_registers(0, 10, unit=1)
# Use the same byte and wordorders
>>> d = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(r.registers, byteorder=Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Big)
>>> d.decode_32bit_float()
120.0
>>> d.decode_32bit_float()
501.29998779296875
>>> d.decode_32bit_float()
-65.19999694824219
>>> d.decode_32bit_float()
140.3000030517578
>>> d.decode_32bit_float()
-202.39999389648438
>>> # Further reads after the registers are exhausted will throw struct error
>>> d.decode_32bit_float()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sanjay/.virtualenvs/be3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymodbus/payload.py", line 440, in decode_32bit_float
    handle = self._unpack_words(fstring, handle)
  File "/Users/sanjay/.virtualenvs/be3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymodbus/payload.py", line 336, in _unpack_words
    handle = unpack(up, handle)
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
>>>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I now have Pymodbus working (thanks to your help).  I have a Modbus master (not PyModbus) housed on a virtual machine behind a router.  I have routing tables set up so that I can ping between the host machine (housing the PyModbus server) and the virtual machine (housing the Modbus master).  How should I set the addressing within the PyModbus server so they can continue to communicate? 
`StartTcpServer(context, identity=identity, address=("?", 502))`
The virtual machine host of the Modbus master has IP address 10.0.10.1 and the non-vritual host has IP address 10.011.1.

Comment: If VM is reachable on its IP `10.0.10.1` You can directly use it or better go with `0.0.0.0` so that all IPV4 addresses are reachable.

Comment: Thank you.  Does it have to be port 502 (typical modbus port) or can it be on any designated port?

Comment: Any port of your choice, The pymodbus examples use `port 5020` because `502` is restricted port and generally requires `sudo` permissions on linux system.